numerical optimization
I got a problem as given here.
Minimize $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 60x_1$
s.t:
$$g_1 = x_1 − 80 \geq 0\\
g_2 = x_1 + x_2 \geq 120$$
I tried to solve using Lagrange multipliers.
Method: Lagrange Multipliers
L(x1, x2, λ1, λ2) = x1^2 + x2^2 + 60x1 + λ1(80 - x1) + λ2(120 - x1 - x2)
KKT Conditions:
∂L/∂x1 = 2x1 + 60 - λ1 = 0
∂L/∂x2 = 2x2 - λ2 = 0
∂L/∂λ1 = 80 - x1 ≥ 0, λ1 ≥ 0, λ1(80 - x1) = 0
∂L/∂λ2 = 120 - x1 - x2 ≥ 0, λ2 ≥ 0, λ2(120 - x1 - x2) = 0
Solving these conditions:
x1 = 80 - λ1/2
x2 = λ2/2
Am I doing it right?. What is the right approach?
Please advise on how to approach these kinds of multiple constraints. I am new to this subject and not sure if the notations and steps are valid.

Note:  $$x_1^2+x_2^2+60x_1=(x_1+30)^2+x_2^2-900$$ So the minimum value is achieved at the shortest distance to $(-30,0).$

note that $x_1 \ge 80,x_2 \ge 120-x_1 $
The function you try to minimize is monotonically increasing with $x_1$ and $x_2 $ but because it is 'more increasing' with $x_1$ than $x_2$ , you will want to minimize $x_1$ and maximize $x_2 $ just up until you meed the constraints, therefore $x_1 =80$ and $x_2 =40$ will give you the optimal solution
